# Help Needed in Installing Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10

Please Kindly give the solution to install Ubuntu 13.10 in my Laptop?

**PC Name:** ***HP Pavilion 15 Notebook (n011Tx)** Notebook PC*

**Problem:** After Full Installation of Ubuntu 13.10 When i boot to the Ubuntu 13.10 Operating System Suddenly it shows a alert **"YOUR SYSTEM IS RUNNING IN LOW GRAPHICS"** after this the Shell Prompt will be displayed

Please kindly help to get Desktop Environment of Ubuntu 13.10 else
please give steps to Install Ubuntu 13.10 on Stated PC/LAPTOP
Or please tell which version of Ubuntu will suite for my PC/LAPTOP

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you should [Install Proprietary drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```